# ajax loading indicator stopped in between

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am saving data on a save button click that calls ajax and passing json data to a controller method but when we save it loading starts and suddenly stop though the data is not saved.

It is not working I have tried it in all way but not working please help me on this.

```html
<button type="button" id="saveDeleg" class="btn_reg_back btnmainsize btnautowidth btngrad btnrds btnbdr btnsavesize " aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe0f4;">@Resources.Resource.Save</button>
```

```js
$('#saveDeleg').click(function() {
  var response = Validation();
  if (!response) {
    return false;
  }

  $("#overlay").show();
  $('.loading').show();

  if ($('#organName').val() == '') {
    $('#validorganisation').show();
    return false;
  } else {
    $('#validorganisation').hide();
  }
  //Contact name
  var SubDelegation = $('#subdelegation').is(':checked');
  var CopyNotification = $('#copynotification').is(':checked');
  var ArrangementId = $("#ArrangementId").val();
  var paramList = {
    ArrangementId: ArrangementId,
    ArrangementName: $('#arrangName').val(),
    OrganisationName: $('#organName').val(),
    OrganisationId: $('#OrganisationId').val(),
    ContactName: $('#contactName').val(),
    ContactId: $('#ContactId').val(),
    SubDelegation: $('#subdelegation').is(':checked'),
    CopyNotification: $('#copynotification').is(':checked'),
    ContactType: $('#ContactType').val(),
    SelectedTypeName: $("input[name$=SelectedType]:checked").val()
  };

  setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
      async: false,
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("SaveDelegation", "Structures")',
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify(paramList),
      processdata: true,
      success: function(result) {
        //stopAnimation()
        paramList = null;
        if (result == 0) {
          window.location.href = '../Structures/MyDelegationArrangement';
        } else if (result == 1) {
          window.location.href = '../Structures/CreateDelegation';
        } else if (result == 2) {
          window.location.href = '../Home/Error';
        } else if (result == 3) {
          window.location.href = '../Account/Login';
        } else {
          //validation message
          alert('Error');
        }
      },
      error: function() {},
      complete: function() {
        $("#overlay").hide();
        $('.loading').hide();
      }
    });
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: The problem with the loading indicator is because you used `async: false` which locks up the UI. Remove that setting. Also, if the data is not being saved I guess your AJAX is returning an error, so check the console to see the response code. You could also put some logic in the `error` callback function to give you some information on whats happened too.

Comment: Great thanks It works.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept your answer.

Comment: No problem - added it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the loading indicator is because you used `async: false` which locks up the UI. Remove that setting.

Also note that if the data is not being saved I would assume that your AJAX call is returning an error. If so, check the console to see the response code. It may also be worth putting some logic in the `error` callback function to give you some information on whats happened, as well as inform your users about what to do next.